# Swagger Editor shows “Failed to fetch” error

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I also meet a similar problem like [M.Shute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375605/swagger-editor-shows-failed-to-fetch-error), but differently, I have a full control to my server-end codes. When I copy the Curl request provided by Swagger Editor and run it in CMD, it returns the value I expect.

`-X POST "http://localhost:3000/users/register" -H  "accept: application/xml" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  \"username\": \"Tester7\",  \"password\": \"Tester7\"}"
Successfully registered user!`

I don't have any securityDefinitions in my API. And I definitely config the response status in my express codes.

```
User.register(user, password, function(error, account) {
    if (error) {
            res.status(400).send(error);
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send('Successfully registered user!');
        }
});
```

Every time I execute the swagger test, the console value is

`OPTIONS /users/register 200 4.040 ms - 4`

Why the swagger use the option method and how can I figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some problems with the [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/22824372).

I set the header of the response to figure it out.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://petstore.swagger.io');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, api_key, Authorization');
  next();
});
```