# Where the Swagger pretty HTML code?

Tags: html, swagger

There are only **ugly** HTML pages as download (HTML, HTML2 and dynamic all ugly), but the site, eg. edited `https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/{user}/{project}/{version}`
(and many others!) offers pretty HTML interface... How to download this pretty HTML?

Complete and autonomous HTML code (file or zip of files).

I have a good and valid `swagger.yaml` or `swagger.json` file of my API, so another solution is to run a open sourse (plug and play!) tool with my API-description file.

---

### The pretty:

[image]

### The ugly:

[image]

Comment: Updating with a fresh official answer, ["As for generating pretty HTML docs - this is **currently unsupported**"](https://github.com/yvasiyarov/swagger/issues/131#issuecomment-347437057).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Swagger-UI at https://github.com/swagger-api say on Readme

> If you are looking for plain ol' HTML/JS/CSS, [download the latest release](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/latest) and copy the contents of the `/dist` folder to your server.

To install your OpenAPI JSON there, [change the URL of this line of `swagger-initializer.js`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/swagger-initializer.js#L6),

```js
    url: "MY_URL", //"https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
```

### Old answer

Thanks to [@tleyden at swagger-ui/issues](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3229#issuecomment-311830539) for good clues!

Use the index and `assets` folder of this project, https://github.com/okfn-brasil/swagger-ui-html

Comment: See also problem with cross-domain when using standalone solutions, at https://stackoverflow.com/q/43375605/287948

Answer (score 6):

The "pretty interface" on your screenshot is **[Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)**. It's free and open-source. There's a demo at http://petstore.swagger.io, where you can load your own YAML/JSON files from an URL and see how they would be rendered.

To use Swagger UI locally:

1. Go to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui and download the repository as ZIP:

   [image: Download Swagger UI]
2. Edit the `dist\index.html` file and change the line

   ```
   url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
   ```

   to the URL of your Swagger .json or .yaml file, e.g.

   ```
   url: "http://api.mysite.com/swagger.json",
   ```
3. (Optional) Add/change other [configuration parameters](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md) in the `SwaggerUIBundle` initialization code in `dist\index.html`.
4. Open the `dist\index.html` file in your browser to preview your API docs.

   **Note:** If the spec does not load or "try it out" does not work, you probably need to enable CORS on the your server. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/cors.md and https://enable-cors.org.
5. Upload the files from the `dist` folder somewhere to your server - and now you have pretty API docs too!

Alternatively, [**SwaggerHub**](https://swaggerhub.com) (which you mentioned) provides cloud hosting for Swagger specs among other things, and has Swagger UI integrated. You can import your Swagger .json/.yaml files there and have your API docs hosted on SwaggerHub. A [free plan](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/pricing/) is available.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Helen (!). Hum... I see, change the *petstore* to my URL works only... But you not show how to download a **standalone** (autonomous) HTML with it.  Can you show a step-by-step instructions to do it? Whithout download there are no solution to the problem of the question.

Comment: PS: "from the repository, edit dist\index.html" not make sense without an URL or detailed instructions

Comment: Thanks @Helen for the instructions (!)... But it is the same **"with advertaising" page** (with the "swagger explore" green navigation bar)... Is a *half solution* (up  voted but not accepted): seems very difficult to take off the advertaising bar... It will waste my time with no guarantee of success.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, I suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=swagger-ui&title=How+to+hide+top+bar+in+Swagger+UI+3.x?) about that. Follow-up questions are not suitable for comments.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: Which project is that "official" info from? Swagger UI's official repository is https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.

Comment: Helen, OOPS, sorry, we can delete. Was a problem with HTML static but the official is not there.