# Simple swagger documentation for Spring REST Greeting service

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I used the [Spring REST service implementation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to learn Swagger.

Service on GET - http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Betlista returns

```json
{
  "id":5,
   "content":"Hello, Betlista!"
}
```

So I created YAML file for Swagger as:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  title: "Spring REST"
host: "localhost:8080"
basePath: "/"
tags:
- name: "Greeting"
schemes:
- "http"
paths:
  /greeting:
    get:
      operationId: "greeting"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "name"
        in: "query"
        required: false
        type: "string"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GreetingResponse"
definitions:
  GreetingResponse:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
      content:
        type: "string"
```

The problem is, when I tried to execute it using "Try it out" button.

It seems (from Chrome's Network tab in developer tools) like there is no response:

[image: Not working call from Swagger editor]

...while regular call in browser works fine

[image: Working from Chrome]

**edit:** as I mentioned in comments, I verified curl generated by swagger and it works as expected - `curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Betlista" -H "accept: application/json"`

At the moment I'm looking into CORS topic (which makes no sense to me as documentation and service are both on localhost), I see in Chrome console this:

[image: CORS error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger Editor shows "Failed to fetch" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375605/swagger-editor-shows-failed-to-fetch-error)

Comment: @RobEvans Thanks, I'll check and let you know! I can see at first sight that I have there that `Failed to fetch`.

Comment: seems likely swagger has console errors if the requests are otherwise identical and one is failing and the plain Chrome request is not. If you try curl as well, and that works, its almost certainly swagger thats broken, not the endpoint/request

Comment: @RobEvans I checked and it's not solving my problem - there is no authorization, but in console I can see, thank you, `swagger-ui.js:1 GET http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Betlista net::ERR_FAILED` I'll try Google for the same...

Comment: @RobEvans I tried `curl`, that worked well...

Comment: can you supply the code for `"#/definitions/GreetingResponse"` maybe its a parsing error?

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact problem of the service, not of the Swagger Editor.

I'm still looking for a solution, which is described [here](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/ui/cors):

> CORS uses special HTTP headers to allow cross-domain requests. The "try it out" feature requires the following headers in API responses:
>
> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://host.from.which.the.request.came
> Vary: Origin
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ResponseHeader1, ResponseHeader2, ...
> ```

I tried to use [Spring REST sevice with CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/), which on `curl -I http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Betlista` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37
Date: Mon, 02 Nov 2020 13:42:15 GMT
```

but this is still not working...

As I said, it's not the Swagger Editor problem, but service problem.

CORS check can be turned off in Chrome starting it `chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/tmp` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) which is of course not recommended, so I consider this as a workaround only.

What I used at the end was this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022289/384674

edit: later I used - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40300363/384674